Fill in exmpty spaces along screw threads
So I am trying to make screw threads for a pen. I would like to solidify the inner part of the screw threads, as I am planning to make 3D prints out of my model.
Does anyone have a simple way how to achieve this?
I highly appreciate any help on this.



This depends on how you want your model to look like at the end. For 3D-printing, the entire model needs to have thickness, so the flat parts of the screw at the top and bottom need to be solidified as well either way.
If you want the inner part of the screw threads to be screwable as well, applying a solidify modifier might be enough. Otherwise, if you want the inner wall to be flat, it you could just extrude the upper and lower edge loops of the cylinder and use the Bridge Edge Loops function to get a solid object for 3D-printing, like this:


Thank you very much for this advice. Very useful. Just one question. In your example you extrude the edges along the normals. How do I achieve that?
Please apologize I am quite new to Blender. Usually when I extrude, I can only extrude along the X Y Z axis. Only if I chose faces I can extrude along the normals as you do it in your example.

@teodorw. I selected the edges, pressed E to extrude them, but did not move them from where they were generated, I just clicked instantly. Then, with the newly generated edges still selected, I pressed S to enter scaling mode and Shift + Z to scale the edges only on the X- and Y-Axes. You can then move the mouse to scale the edges inwards or outwards however you'd like.

FWIW a useful tool to enable is a built-in addon: Edit Mesh Tools. Then when you press Ctrl+E in edit mode, Offset Edges > and you can do this kind of operation alot more cleanly than can be achieved with the Scale > Shift + [Axis] method.

Thanks a million for your help. Very useful!

@Mantelmann A tip to do this extrude + scale even more efficiently: it's not necessary to click first to avoid moving the extrusion (even if, I would specify to right-click instead of left-click to make sure you did not move it accidentally a little bit), but if you hit S immediately after E to extrude, the move action will be abandoned and instead you will directly scale the extruded edges.
